# OnClick item selection in MaterialSearchView android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I am using Material search view developed by Miguel Catalan from [this repo](https://github.com/MiguelCatalan/MaterialSearchView). I have list of suggestions and when user selects the suggestion he/she should see filtered results. My problem here is nothing happens on text writing event or option selection. I have added this in my main activity file:-

```
    MaterialSearchView searchView = (MaterialSearchView) findViewById(R.id.search_view);
    //searchView.setSuggestions(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.query_suggestions));
    String [] suggestions = {"Item1","Item2","Item3"};
    searchView.setSuggestions(suggestions);
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new MaterialSearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            Log.d("here",query);
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            Log.d("here",newText);

            return false;
        }

    });

    searchView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Log.d("ItemClick","onItemClick,");
        }
    });

    searchView.setOnSearchViewListener(new MaterialSearchView.SearchViewListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSearchViewShown() {
            Log.d("here","search");
        }

        @Override
        public void onSearchViewClosed() {
            Log.d("here","search");
        }
    });
```

I don't see anything in debug log which means no methods were called. Could anyone tell what can be the reason here?[image]
    }

Answer (score 2):

i have very  quick and easy answer for you.

just copy below code in OnCreateOptionMenu() method.

```
searchView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {        
                  searchView.dismissSuggestions();
                  searchView.closeSearch();
                  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 //show search result after clearing/closing search.
    }
});
```

here i am using [This Material SearchView](https://github.com/MiguelCatalan/MaterialSearchView)

hope this is might help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
searchView.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Log.d("ItemClick","onItemClick,");
    }
});
```

Please use onitemSelectedListener  instead of onitemclickListener. Hope this helps.

Comment: MaterialSearchView does not have setOnItemSelectedListener() method just setOnItemClickListener(),so can't use this :\

Answer (score 0):

Set Adapter for SearchView, OnItemClick will work

```
mSearchView.setAdapter(new SearchAdapter(this, results));
```

With results is String[] and
you must import SearchAdapter
`import com.miguelcatalan.materialsearchview.SearchAdapter;`